# NSPredicate for Array of Quickblox Custom Objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nspredicate, quickblox

I have a `NSMutableArray` which contains a large number of QuickBlox Custom Objects (`QBCOCustomObject` class).

When my user's enter name information into a textfield, I want to filter my tableview to show results based on their search.

Here's how I would get the user's full name from the custom class...

```
for (QBCOCustomObject *object in self.userArray) { 
    NSString *c = [object.fields[@"fullName"];
    NSLog (@"%@", c);
}
```

In the method below I am trying to setup the predicate but I'm struggling to find the correct format for the predicate. Can anyone help?

```
- (void)textFieldDidChange :(UITextField *)theTextField {

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(fullName CONTAINS[cd] %@)", self.searchBar.text];
    self.userArray = [[self.userArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: Try `fields.fullName CONTAINS[cd] %@`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working example:

```
NSMutableArray *initialArray = [NSMutableArray array];

QBCOCustomObject *object1 = [QBCOCustomObject customObject];
object1.fields = [@{
    @"fullName": @"Igor",
    @"age": @(27)
} mutableCopy];
[initialArray addObject:object1];
//
QBCOCustomObject *object2 = [QBCOCustomObject customObject];
object2.fields = [@{
                    @"fullName": @"Bob",
                    @"age": @(27)
                    } mutableCopy];
[initialArray addObject:object2];
//
QBCOCustomObject *object3 = [QBCOCustomObject customObject];
object3.fields = [@{
                    @"fullName": @"Igorio",
                    @"age": @(27)
                    } mutableCopy];
[initialArray addObject:object3];

NSLog(@"initialArray: %@", initialArray);

NSPredicate *bPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fields.fullName CONTAINS 'Igor'"];
NSArray *filteredArray = [initialArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:bPredicate];

NSLog(@"filteredArray: %@", filteredArray);
```

It returns the 'Igor' and 'Igorio' objects and skip 'Bob'

Here is a good tutorial about NSPredicate with great examples:

http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/

Comment: thanks, and also to @Larme for his comment on my question for helping me get it right